# pagination in mvc action result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to mvc and entity framework, so I'm trying but can't set up here paging.Some prepositions..I'm filling list with some query, and then that list iterating in view.Depending on results in that list i want to set up a paging.Thanks a lot.

```
     public ActionResult Gallery(int id, string TopicSystemName)
      {
        var gallery = _galleryRepo.GetById(id);
        var query = _galleryRepo.Table;


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TopicSystemName))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.EffectType.Contains(TopicSystemName));

        }

         var galleries = new List<GalleryRecord>(query.ToList());
      //  var galleries =  new PagedList<GalleryRecord>(query.ToList(), command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);

        List<GalleryRecord> lista = new List<GalleryRecord>();
        GalleryRecord galleryRecord = new GalleryRecord();
        foreach (var a in galleries)
        {
            if (a.EffectType == TopicSystemName)
            {
                gallery = _galleryRepo.GetById(a.GalleryId);
                gallery.Images = gallery.Images != null && gallery.Images.Any() ?
         gallery.Images.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList() :
         _imageRepo.Table.Where(x => x.GalleryId == gallery.GalleryId).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();

                lista.Add(gallery);
            }
        }

        // if (gallery == null) return Content("");


        //if (gallery.ExtractFromPdf) return View("GalleryCanvas", gallery);
        ViewBag.lis = lista;
        return View(gallery);
    }





     foreach (var a in ViewBag.lis)
       {

        foreach (var galleryImageRecord in a.Images)
        {
            <div class="thumbnail1 img-responsive " style="position:relative">
                <div class="image1 img-responsive ">
                    <div class="img-responsive  fade col-sm-@(colClassNm) col-sm-@(colClassNm) col-sm-12 col-xs-12 test" style="min-height:130px;padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 0px;">
                        <div style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center; border: 0px double #dedede;">

                            <a class="fancybox-thumb " rel="fancybox-thumb" title="@galleryImageRecord.Caption" href="@galleryImageRecord.FilePath" data-lightbox="test-123">
                                <img title="@galleryImageRecord.Caption" src="@galleryImageRecord.FilePath" alt="@galleryImageRecord.Caption" width="300" height="280" />
                            </a>

                        </div>

        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you start with [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq for this:

```
lista.Take(10) //return number records that you want.
```